# Connect to wireless network with Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, network-manager, 17.04, vmware

I have a **VMware** virtual machine running **Ubuntu 17.04**. My PC is connected to my WLAN but the VM isn't in the network. I suspect that the network card isn't install on my VM. I can connect to LAN to install drivers but I can't always be connected.

How can install the driver (if this is the problem)?

Comment: You don't need to connect the VM to a wireless network. VMs use connections of the host system.

Comment: So, why my virtual machine doesn't recognize my wlan?

Comment: It shouldn't recognize "your wlan". It should have a virtual lan connection if you configured it correctly. I don't know what is the VM, and how is it configured.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a virtual machine with **VMware**, you can use one of several types of [network connections](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-3B504F2F-7A0B-415F-AE01-62363A95D052.html).

- **bridged networking**, where the VM has direct access to the network. Here the VM must acquire a different IP address (e.g. from a DHCP server) and may require bringing the network interfaces up/down (e.g. by using `ip link` 
  or `ifconfig`) in the VM each time you change of network.
- **NAT**, where the VM connects to the network (and internet) through the host system. Using this type of connection, the VM is not accessible from the outside.
- **host-only**, where the VM connects only to the host system.

I think you [must use a NAT connection](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_nat_advanced.html). using this connection, your VM will have network/internet access while the host system has access. If you need to access servers/services in the VM you may configure a port forwarding for NAT.

If you need information on bringing interfaces up/down, [please look here](http://mirrors.deepspace6.net/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/x1028.html).

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm connect but I have curiosity. My address LAN is 192.168.1.0/24 while the ip of my VM is 192.168.56.1. The VM is correctly in the network infact the ping works but why the VM has ...51.1 while the network is ...1.0?

Comment: If you are using NAT, the VM and the host system are connected together using a virtual switch. They belong to a private network different than the network you use in the host. The VM obtains its IP address from a dedicated VMware DHCP and access the external network/internet through a NAT proxy. -- Your VM will get an IP address from a different subnet -- you may check https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_nat.html and https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-144D22BA-298E-4293-8137-B631AD7BF694.html